# Probability that $1,2$ are in the same set on randomly halving $\{1,...,10\}$?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, solution-verification

**Textbook problem:** The integers from $1$ to $10$ inclusive are partitioned into two sets of five elements each. What is the probability that $1$ and $2$ are in the same set?

**My solution:** $2/9$. The total number of partitions would be $10 \choose 5$. If $1$ and $2$ are in the same set, then there are $8 \choose 3$ ways left to create the set that contains them since two of the numbers have already been chosen.  Hence, the probability is ${8 \choose 3} / {10 \choose 5}$ which is $2/9$.

**Textbook answer:** $4/9$.

**Question:** What am I missing in my reasoning? Should I be doubling the number of ways to create a set with $1$ and $2$ in it for some reason?

**Textbook:** The Art Of Problem Solving (Vol. 1) by Rusczyk, Chapter 26.

Comment: The issue is that you are switching points of view on whether choosing 5-element sets $A$ and $B$ is the same as choosing sets $B$ and $A$.

Comment: Can you expand on that?  Switching points of view in how I am counting for the numerator versus how I am counting for the denominator?

Comment: @UngarLinski You count $\binom{10}5$ in the denominator as being the ways to select a set of five from all ten items.  We can do this by selecting (A) both $1$ and $2$ and three from the eight others, (B) either $1$ or $2$ and four others, or (C) neither $1$ nor $2$ and five others.$$\tbinom{10}5=\tbinom 22\tbinom83+\tbinom21\tbinom84+\tbinom20\tbinom85$$But wait! For every set we select, a complement is created, so (A) and (C) both create the favored outcome, so the probability we want is $$\dfrac{\tbinom22\tbinom83+\tbinom20\tbinom85}{\tbinom{10}5}$$

Comment: You forgot to account for the $\displaystyle\binom21$ ways to choose that one set where both $1$ and $2$ are.

Comment: No @ultralegend5385  We select both 1 and 2 and three others. OR we select neither 1 nor 2 and five others (which places 1 and 2 in the complementary set).

Comment: @GrahamKemp: That's the same thing isn't it?

Comment: Which is why you don't do it again.  It was already accounted.

Comment: @GrahamKemp Is the decomposition of 10-choose-5 as the sum of (A), (B), and (C) a combinatorial identity or were you just using like exhaustion/counting all scenarios?

Comment: @UngarLinski  Yes.   It is a combinatorial identity proven by counting.

Comment: @GrahamKemp Your answer makes the most sense to me; it follows my original line of reasoning and shows that I missed a case or scenario.  One reason I missed it is b/c I originally was thinking of a ``multinomial" where $\frac{10!}{5!5!}$ creates/counts two sets of five elements each like in pairs of sets if that makes sense.

Comment: Indeed.  The point was that the denominator counted ways to create **two** sets of five elements, so *if you use that* your numerator must also count ways to create **two** sets of five elements --that also satisfies the favoured condition of 1 and 2 being in the same set (... **but which**?).

Comment: Likewise, if you count ways to select 1 and four from nine other elements in the denominator, then the numerator should count ways to select 1 and four other elements of which 2 is included.$$\dfrac{\tbinom 11\tbinom 83}{\tbinom 94}$$

Comment: @GrahamKemp Ah.  I think I see.  Then this ``multinomial" approach, if you will, of looking at pairs of sets or of two sets at a time, is such that the sets are distinguishable within the pairs which is why you say **but which**.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/136714/discussion-between-graham-kemp-and-ungar-linski).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The total number of partitions would be 10-choose-5. If 1 and 2 are in the same set, then then there are 8-choose-3 ways left to create the set that contains them since two of the numbers have already been chosen.

$\binom{10}5$ counts the ways to select a set of five elements from ten. But do notice that each such selection will also create an additional set of five elements: its relative complement.

There are $\tbinom 22\tbinom 83$ ways to select elements `1`, `2`, and three from the remaining eight elements into a set of five elements.  However, there are *also* $\tbinom20\tbinom 85$ ways to select five from those eight elements which will leave `1` and `2` in the complement set.  The favoured event is the union of both these disjoint cases.

$\def\lfrac#1#2{\left.{#1}\middle/{#2}\right.}$So the probability we seek is $\lfrac{\left[{\tbinom22\tbinom 83+\tbinom20\tbinom 85}\right]}{\tbinom {10}5}$ which equals $\lfrac{2\tbinom 83}{\tbinom{10}5}$ or simply $\lfrac 4 9$.

We can validate this by noting that there are ${\tbinom21\tbinom84}$ ways to select one from $\{1,2\}$ and four from the eight other elements, counting all ways to place `1` and `2` in separate sets, so the probability we seek is $\lfrac{\left[\tbinom{10}5-\tbinom21\tbinom84\right]}{\tbinom{10}5}$, which is indeed $\lfrac 49$.

Unsurprisingly, since $\tbinom{10}5=\tbinom 20\tbinom85+\tbinom 21\tbinom84+\tbinom 22\tbinom83$ .

---

Alternatively, as @BrianTung notes, there are $\tbinom 94$ *distinct* ways to partition the ten element set into two sets of five elements.  This counts ways to select one set that contains a particular element and one which does not.  We can choose any of the ten elements to be the set identifier, but it is quite useful to use `1`.

The count of partitions where `2` is in the set containing `1` (the favoured event) is $\tbinom 8 3$. So the probability we seek is $\lfrac{\tbinom 8 3}{\tbinom 9 4}$, which is $\lfrac 49$.

(Note: We get the same answer if we choose `2` as the identifying element.)

---

We might make things harder for ourself and choose another element as the identifier; such as `10`.  In this case we should note that the favoured event is satisfied when `1` and `2` are both in the identified set, or when they are both in its complement.

So the probability we seek is $\lfrac{\left[{\tbinom22\tbinom 72+\tbinom20\tbinom 74}\right]}{\tbinom 94}$, which again equals $\lfrac 49$.

---

A different approach might be to count distinct ways two special positions might placed when the ten elements are lined up, which is $\tbinom{10}2$.  The favoured event is when those two positions are both among the first five, or the last five.  Those positions are for elements `1` and `2`.

So the probability we seek is $\lfrac{\left[\tbinom 52\tbinom 50+\tbinom 50\tbinom 52\right]}{\tbinom{10}2}$.  This is unsurprisingly equal to $\lfrac 49$.

---

However you decide to count equally probable atoms of the total space, then the atoms of the favoured event should be counted in the same general manner.  Also make sure you add the counts for all disjoint cases that comprise the favoured event.

Remember too that *sometimes* counting the *disfavoured* atoms might be easier.

Answer (score 8):

One way of looking at your error is that, yes, there are $\binom{10}{5}$ five-element subsets altogether, but only half of them contain $1$. Of those that contain $1$, $\binom{8}{3}$ *also* contain $2$. So the desired probability is

$$
\frac{\binom{8}{3}}{\frac12\binom{10}{5}} = \frac{56}{\frac{252}{2}} = \frac{4}{9}
$$

---

Alternatively, you can observe that whichever subset $1$ is in contains four of the remaining nine numbers, so the probability that $2$ is one of those four is $\frac49$.

Comment: So to be clear I have to take the count out of those that contain 1 (or 2 for that matter)?

Comment: I don't understand your characterization clearly enough to say whether it's right or not. The probability (assuming a uniform distribution of subsets) that $1$ and $2$ are in the same subset can be thought of as $P(\text{$2$ is in subset $A$} \mid \text{$1$ is in subset $A$})$ (because by symmetry, that probability is identical for subset $B$). A method for calculating that is to find the subsets that $1$ is in, and ask what proportion of those also contain $2$.

Comment: Of course, there's no reason why $1$ is privileged here; we could start the calculation with $2$ instead, and we'll get the same answer.